# get the selected row of datagrid i.e on click in mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, icommand, relaycommand

i want to get the selected row of datagrid i.e on click in mvvm.i have below code i want to use it in MVVM,but not able to do so.Please let me know how to convert below 3 line s in mvvm using relay comand and Icommand

```
DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)dgProjectComponents.SelectedItem;
            int index = dgProjectComponents.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
            string ProjectComponentID = Convert.ToString(dataRow.Row.ItemArray[2].ToString());

**Xaml of datagrid:**


<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}" Background="{Binding ElementName=gd,Path=Background}" ItemsSource="{Binding ManualDataTable}"   x:Name="dgProjectComponents">
                                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="50" IsReadOnly="True">
                                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                            <DataTemplate >
                                                                <TextBlock  Height="10" Width="10" Background="{Binding ColorDefinition}" ></TextBlock>
                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProjectComponentID}" Visibility="Hidden" Width="100" Header="ProjectComponentID" />
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="140" />



                                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="50">
                                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                                <TextBlock><Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DelProjectComponent,ElementName=ProjectTabWindow}"><Image Source="/img/Close.png"   x:Name="imgProjectComponentDelete" Height="15" Width="20"></Image></Hyperlink></TextBlock>
                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                                            </DataGrid>
                                            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Why have you hidden most of your code out of view? Can you really not display it properly for us?

Answer (score 1):

You have data bound your `ManualDataTable` collection to the `ItemsSource` property of your `DataGrid` and your `SelectedRow` property to the `SelectedItem` property. If your `SelectedRow` property is of the same type as the items in your `ManualDataTable` collection, then you can use it to reference the selected item from the `DataGrid`.

Therefore, you have no need to find a certain column from a `DataGridRow`, because you can access the properties of your class as normal... so instead of your three lines of code, you can simply do this (assuming that you have an `Id` property in your class):

```
string ProjectComponentID = SelectedRow.Id;
```

Comment: :How could i get the index of current cell of the column the from above mentioned suggestion of yours?

Comment: I just showed you how. You use the name of the property that feeds that column in the UI... I quite clearly said *assuming that you have an Id property* as I assumed that would be the name of the correct property.